# How to insert results from database in associative array

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a query which gets all policy ids from database.I want to put all results in associative array, to look like this :

```
[0]=>Q-CID-14328097
[1]=>Q-CID-1507193624
[2]=>id3
```

This is my code :

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM wp_frm_items WHERE user_id=%d ORDER BY created_at DESC", 97));
$i = 0;

if ($results) {
    foreach($results as $row) {
        $policy_id = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s", 203, $row->id));
        $policy_transaction_type = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s", 390, $row->id));
        $policy_transaction_type = $policy_transaction_type[0]->meta_value;
        $policy_id = $policy_id[0]->meta_value;
        $array = array($policy_id);

}
}
```

But this returns :

```
Array ( [0] => Q-CID-14328097 ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => Q-CID-14328097 ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => Q-CID-14328097 ) Array ( [0] => Q-CID-1507193624 ) Array ( [0] => Q-CID-1510050174 ) Array ( [0] => Q-CID-1511814120 ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set $array each time. You can set it once before the loop, then insert elements to it:

```
$array=array();    
foreach($results as $row) {
            $policy_id = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s", 203, $row->id));
            $policy_transaction_type = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=%d AND item_id=%s", 390, $row->id));
            $policy_transaction_type = $policy_transaction_type[0]->meta_value;
            $policy_id = $policy_id[0]->meta_value;
            $array[] =$policy_id;

    }
```

That's all